# HPLIP crashes when setting up printer (Ubuntu 22.10)

Tags: printing, hp, hplip

I'm using Ubuntu 22.10 and I'm trying to set up my HP printer with HPLIP.

First I set up manually putting in the IP-address of the printer and it recognises the printer. However, once I click on "next" the HPLIP freezes.

I don't know if this will help, but when I give in `hp-doctor` in the terminal it throws an error:

```
-Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/hp-doctor", line 276, in <module>
    dep.core.init()
  File "/usr/share/hplip/installer/core_install.py", line 523, in init
    self.get_distro()
  File "/usr/share/hplip/installer/core_install.py", line 661, in get_distro
    if 'MX' in distro_release_name:
NameError: name 'distro_release_name' is not defined
```

Comment: Printer model and connection method?

Comment: Yes of course, my HP OfficeJet Pro 8022 is connected via WiFi. My PC is connected via ethernet to router (don't know if that makes a difference).

Answer (score 1):

For those who requires HPLIP for their printer / scanner, here is a workaround to fix the bug in the software:

```
sudo sed -i "s/get_distro_std_name(os_name)/get_distro_name()/" /usr/share/hplip/base/password.py
```

This will replace occurrences of the `get_distro_std_name(os_name)` function by the new `get_distro_name()` function. It seems that HP devs forgot two occurrences when they refactored this file :)

Answer (score 0):

This device is designed for driverless printing.
HPLIP is not needed. Executing `driverless` gives
a **URI**. Set up a print queue with

`lpadmin -p PRINTER_NAME -v "URI" -E -m everywhere`

Substitute for URI, of course. PRINTER_NAME can be
what you choose. Test printing with

`lp -d PRINTER_NAME /etc/nsswitch.conf`